# Receiving Socket stops suddenly after sometime

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I am working on project works on SMPP protocol. Infinitely it listens to server and accept socket. After receiving socket it creates a handler which receives data and process it according to SMPP protocol. After some point(1 or 2 weeks) it stops receiving socket. It doesn't throw any exception but just waiting on line *. I don't know what is the problem and how can i fix it. Notice that socket count is not more than 30. So we haven't problem about alive socket count limit.
And notice that the other sockets before created are alive and working.App recieves data from these sockets and process: receive sms-es and send sms-es from these sockets. After restarting app it is working. I think it is not the solution.

```
private void process() {
    try {
        //line *.waiting for receiving new socket. Problem is on this point
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        //creating a handler that recieve data and process it according to SMPP protocol
        StandardConnectionHandler sch = new StandardConnectionHandler(socket);
        new Thread(sch).start();
        smsc.getConnectionHandlers().add(sch);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "exception in accepting a connection", ex);
    } finally {
        process();//if it is done.recieved a new socket call back again
        //it is infinite recursive procedure
    }
}
```

Comment: well, 1-2 weeks i think its normal behaviour. What about some `watch dog`, service that should start socket again on closing?

Comment: socket doesn't close it is working.I noticed that all of the sockets before created are alive and working.If socket was closed all of the clients that connected to app must be closed too.Problem is recieving new socket.It just waiting for it.no exception no error

Comment: @MaximShoustin i wrote in my last comment.Please read it.There is not any shutting down, closing problem

Comment: What symptoms do your new clients experience when this happens, and what platform is the server running on?

Answer (score -1):

You didn't post your full code, and the server socket initialization. Nonetheless I think your problem might be related to you not closing all the streams properly.

Comment: i debug all sockets constantly and each client has privilidge to connect one time.I notice again there is no error.In situation you said i should get an error

Comment: Is there any reason for the recursive call or can you switch to a standard while cycle

Comment: i can do it in while(true) too.There isn't any special reason for recursive procedure.What could be the problem in recursive version?

Comment: @Serkhan The problem is that you will eventually get a certain stack overflow. Don't use recursion like this.

Comment: Yup exactly my thoughts you should switch to a while and try it

Comment: @user2430343 However your answer wouldn't explain a block in `accept()`.

Comment: @EJP i don't get stackoverflow.Because accept() method wait for new Socket.So process() method doesn't call recursively without waiting.I notice i don't get any but any exception

Comment: @Serkhan It would take you many thousands or millions of recursions to get a stack overflow, but it will certainly happen some time. Nobody has suggrsted this is the cause of your current problem. If it was, we assume you would have mentioned it. You haven't answered my question.